# Query: "Lab*Feedback" - "LabFeedback.docx" not returned

Tags: search, wildcard-search

File names may have variations such as `Lab Feedback.docx`, `Lab-Feedback.docx`, `Lab_Feedback.docx`, and `LabFeedback.docx`. Unfortunately, SharePoint's search functionality does not support the conventional use of the "*" wildcard, which represents zero or more characters. As a result, searching for "`Lab*Feedback`" does not retrieve "LabFeedback.docx." Is there a specific search query or alternative method available in SharePoint that can retrieve all the mentioned files?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint search wildcards only work on the suffix. `Lab*` There is no perfect query-like option for SharePoint Search. You might try using the contains operator in conjunction with `AND`. For example: `Title:Lab AND Title:Feedback` or something like that with property restrictions.

Another option would be to tag the documents with metadata so that you can use a single property restriction like `IsLabFeedback=1`.

[Review the KQL guidance here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)